# Error in Ajax callback only in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'myUrl/etc'
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    error: function(error) {
      alert('Error');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    },
    timeout: 45000
  });

  function callback(result) {
    // Do what i want
  }
```

People. I am getting an error only in IE8 on a ajax callback , I have no idea what might be or why it is happening.

When i try to run the ajax in all browsers the callback will be called, but in IE the alert error will pop up and the console.log will show:

```
LOG: {
 "readyState": "ok",
 "status": 200,
 "statusText": "success"
}
```

Any idea why is giving this "error" only in IE8???

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?  jQuery 2.x does not support IE8.  The latest in the 1.x series still supports IE8.

Comment: `alert()` does weird things in some versions of IE, sometimes stopping the execution of your code. Use `console.log()` then get back to me.

Comment: i'm using 1.x @jfriend00

Comment: FYI, it is dangerous to set `jsonpCallback: 'callback',`.  Why are you doing that?  That instructs jQuery to use a global function named `callback` as the jsonp callback function rather than have it generate a unique function name for each ajax call.  This also means that you cannot have multiple of these JSONP ajax calls in flight at the same time and necessarily get proper results.

Comment: Also, `jsonp: 'callback',` is already the default value so that is not needed.

Comment: The three arguments to the error callback are  jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown`.  You should see what the last arguments are set to and that may inform you what is going on.

Comment: i remove the jsonp and changed the name of jsonpCallback, but didn't worked.. =(.. this could be a backend error?

Comment: jqXHR: parserror, textStatus: callback was not called, errorThrown: undefined

Comment: Did you make sure you cleared you cache after changing your code?

Comment: Yep, i'm clean the cache every time i change this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved before

> Add this to your script somewhere before your AJAX call (only verified
>   in IE8, not other IE's):
>
> ```
> jQuery.ajaxSetup({
>         xhr: function() {
>                 //return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
>                 try{
>                     if(window.ActiveXObject)
>                         return new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
>                 } catch(e) { }
>
>                 return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
>             }
>     });
> ```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557532/jquery-ajax-requests-failing-in-ie8-with-message-error-this-method-cannot-be-c)